# labeling results into List?

Tags: prolog, clpfd

I want write a predicate that can sum_all the lucky number using the predict lucky/5

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

lucky(A,B,C,D,N) :-
L = [A,B,C,D],
L ins 0..9,
N #= A*1000+B*100+C*10+D,
A+B #= C+D,
labeling([],L).

sum_all():-
% I want to write a code that computes the sum of all lucky numbers
```

Comment: `sum_all() :- ...` is a syntax error. Prolog doesn't use that syntax for empty argument lists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if your Prolog has library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate)), you can do

```
?- aggregate_all((count,sum(N)), lucky(_,_,_,_,N), (Count,Sum)).
Count = 670,
Sum = 3349665.
```